# R function masking scope conflict between data.table and lubridate

Tags: r, scope, data.table, lubridate

EDIT: See simple fix below.

---

I'm running into some odd behavior. Applying via `lapply` multiple functions within the `j` expression of a data.table works when I explicitly name the library in case 1. In case 2, if I don't name the library, it works the first time, but if I call the same line a second time, it fails with the error message: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : could not find function "f"`

```
# Case 1
unloadNamespace('data.table')
unloadNamespace('lubridate')
require(data.table)
require(lubridate)
dt <- data.table(x=as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 00:53:00", tz="Japan"))
dt[, c('year','month', 'day') := lapply(c(lubridate::year, lubridate::month, lubridate::day), function(f) f(x) )] # passes
dt[, c('year','month', 'day') := lapply(c(lubridate::year, lubridate::month, lubridate::day), function(f) f(x) )] # passes

# Case 2
unloadNamespace('data.table')
unloadNamespace('lubridate')
require(data.table)
require(lubridate)
dt <- data.table(x=as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 00:53:00", tz="Japan"))
dt[, c('year','month', 'day') := lapply(c(year, month, day), function(f) f(x) )] # passes
dt[, c('year','month', 'day') := lapply(c(year, month, day), function(f) f(x) )] # fails
```

What's causing this strange behavior? Is there a solution other than the explicit scoping `lubridate::function`?

---

## EDIT:

As per @Frank's comment below, the problem was that `data.table` was interpreting `year` and `month` as referencing its columns instead of the `lubridate` functions. Changing the column names fixed it:

```
# Case 2
unloadNamespace('data.table')
unloadNamespace('lubridate')
require(data.table)
require(lubridate)
dt <- data.table(x=as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 00:53:00", tz="Japan"))
dt[, c('y1','y2', 'y3') := lapply(c(year, month, day), function(f) f(x) )] # passes
dt[, c('y1','y2', 'y3') := lapply(c(year, month, day), function(f) f(x) )] # passes
```

However, as per @FrankH's comment, it's probably best to explicitly specify `lubridate::function` to remove any doubt over which of the two packages masked the other.

Comment: Um, it looks in its own scope first, where those are the names of columns, not functions.

Comment: You should also be getting a warning message about `year` and `month` being masked from `data.table` when you load `lubridate`. So it might be the most clear/robust to specify `lubridate::year/month` anyway.

Comment: @MikeH. Yeah I got the warning message. Doesn't that mean that `lubridate`'s `year` and `month` now take precedence over those of `data.table`'s?

Comment: @Frank Thank you, that was it!

Comment: Yes, but if you load `data.table` after `lubridate`, the functions will be masked from `lubridate`...hence why it is usually best to specify which package you want your function from when there is overlap

Comment: @MikeH. Okay, I understand. Even though I was loading `lubridate` after `data.table` in my example, you're right that it's not a very safe approach - especially if the code is called from somewhere else that affects the order of loadings. You're right, it's more robust to specify explicitly. Even though that wasn't the main problem here, thanks for the advice!